# Gmail based \ Gmail integrated personal CRM

Tags: gmail, crm

I'm looking for a Web Application \ Browser add-on that will supply basic CRM capabilities, with good integration with Gmail

Basically the main feature would be to track conversations, but unlike regular Gmail conversations it should allow:

- group several Gmail threads to a single "meta-conversation"
- allow adding notes or other information (preferably with structured forms for tasks, phone calls, etc.) to the thread
- allow editing the notes I added

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's very close integration, but [Zoho CRM](http://www.zoho.com/crm/) does kind of do [Gmail integration](http://www.zoho.com/crm/crm-email.html). That said, I used Zoho for a while and didn't get on too well with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of 37Signals, and while I'm not subscribed to Highrise, I understand that it integrates well with email (in the general sense - it probably doesn't take advantage of specific Gmail features). Here's a link I found that may be helpful:
http://highrisehq.com/emaildropbox